# How to configure gcc to use an alternate glibc?

Tags: gcc, glibc

To use the loader in the alternate **glibc** installation at `/usr/test`, I have change the loader path `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to `/usr/test/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` under the `*link` section in the **gcc specs** file. I have also pointed `CPATH` to `/usr/test/lib/include` and `LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/test/lib`.

Is it the correct way to use the alternate **glibc**?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about correct, but I'd prefer setting up a chroot environment for this sort of testing. You might alternatively use the LD_PRELOAD mechanism.

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes I need to work on systems that I don't have root privilege

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no.

Yes, if glibc in /usr/test is has a version near enough to system glibc.

No, because there is a chance that glibc headers are incompatible to each other. Then gcc fails from the [fix-include mechanism](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52922).